# Multithreading/QOS for Timer

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

For timer related operations is it worth using any QOS?
If yes then which thread should be used or which QOS can we use?

Now here I am creating a Timer and adding it to Runloop:

```
var activityTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.runActivity), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

RunLoop.current.add(activityTimer!, forMode: .common)
```

I have created global object of DispatchQueue with QOS `.userInteractive`:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.timer", qos: .userInteractive)
```

Here I am sending data to API:

```
@objc func runActivity () {
    queue.async {
        self.postDataUsingAPI()
    }
}
```

So which QOS should be appropriate to use here? I want all these activities running in the background only.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can agree that `userInteractive` is wrong, as user interactive is exactly what this code is not. By using a background serial queue you are already saying you don't really care exactly when this code runs. And a timer is already approximate; that is, you are not going to be calling `runActivity` at exact time intervals either. On the other hand the queue is serial so you won't miss or overlap any calls. Finally, you are going to be networking which means you've thrown away all hope of rapid response, as you are using the totally unpredictable network. Thus `.default` or `.utility`, or unspecified, is far more appropriate.

But I would also question your use of a background queue at all. The timer is already effectively running in the background. Moreover, networking itself is already in the background, and your queue won't affect that in any way. I think you should throw your background queue away and let the networking do its usual work in the usual way. The place to worry about what queue you're on is when you get the callback from the network, and that is something you specify in a totally different way.

By the way, your `RunLoop.current.add` is wrong. Delete it. A scheduled timer is already added to the run loop for you; that is exactly what `scheduled` *means*.

Comment: perfect. thanks. For me, this application will be used for the long run so .utility would be better but in the end, I am sending data to the server using API which runs in the background. So is it worth using .utility? again confused.

Comment: I would also question your use of a repeating timer. Networking is unpredictable. No point mindlessly repeating the call if the previous one is failing. Better to launch a single nonrepeating timer each time you finish processing a network call's results.

Comment: No, I'd omit the qos entirely. But as I said, I'd omit the background queue too.

Comment: RunLoop.current.add(activityTimer!, forMode: .common) as it ensures that the timer is executed on the current thread's run loop, and that the run loop is in the correct mode to handle the timer's events.

By adding the timer to a run loop, you allow the run loop to schedule the timer for execution and handle its events, such as firing the timer after a specified interval.

Comment: I know what it does. What you don't know is that you don't need it. So I'm telling you. And don't go quoting docs at me. Two can play at that game. "Use the scheduledTimer(timeInterval:invocation:repeats:) or scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) class method to create the timer _and schedule it on the current run loop in the default mode_." My italics.

Comment: Pleaes don't say thanks in a comment. On Stack Overflow, the way to thank some whose post is the "right" answer and helped you is to _accept_ that answer (the checkmark).

Comment: I don't think you really registered what Matt is telling you. For your application, you don't need, and **shouldn't use**, a background queue. Full stop. QoS doesn't come into it. Run a timer on the main thread, and when it fires, initiate your network task. Apple's networking code runs on a background thread already. It will call your delegate/completion handler on a background queue by default, and you **can** ste the QoS for that queue if you want, although the default background queue it uses is reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Matt [has summarized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75847647/1271826) the concerns well. `Timer` is asynchronous (non-blocking) and your periodic task would appear to be an asynchronous network request (also non-blocking), so introducing a dispatch to yet another queue is completely unnecessary. It actually introduces a tiny inefficiency, regardless of the queue’s QoS.

---

But you ask how one specifies a QoS for timer queue. While your example is not one of them, there actually are rare situations where one wants to have a timer run in the background on a queue of a particular QoS. For example, we might do this if the periodic task is slow and synchronous.

In that scenario, we would not use `Timer` on the main run loop, which then dispatches to some background queue. Instead, we would bypass the main thread entirely. We would simply add a timer to a background queue directly. To do that, rather than a `Timer`, we would use a [`DispatchSourceTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsourcetimer), a GCD-based timer:

```swift
class PeriodicService {
    private var timer: DispatchSourceTimer?
    
    func start() {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".timer.utility", qos: .utility)
        let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)
        timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
            self?.someSlowSynchronousTask()
        }
        timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: 30)
        timer.resume()
        self.timer = timer
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    func someSlowSynchronousTask() { … }
}
```

This avoids any use of the main thread, entirely. Every 30 seconds, it runs that synchronous task on that background queue. Here I am using a [`.utility`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos/1780791-utility) QoS. Or, you might use [`.background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos/1780981-background) QoS. But we consciously avoid [`.userInteractive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos/1780708-userinteractive) (or, worse, [`.userInitiated`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos/1780759-userinitiated)) because we never want a background process to take precedence over something for which the user is actually waiting.

We would call `start` when we want the timer to start. We would call `cancel` when we want the timer to stop. (And, because it is not using a run loop, unlike `Timer`, this will actually stop the timer if this `DispatchSourceTimer` falls out of scope.)

Again, we would not use this to periodically launch a task that is, itself, asynchronous, such as in your example. We would only use this in those rare cases where the task is synchronous and is therefore important to get off the main thread.

Comment: Interesting as usual!

Comment: Thank you. This is very informative and nicely explained.